# How to calculate the p-value of a log-odds ratio, given that the variance depends on the observed frequencies?

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, p-value, odds-ratio, contingency-tables

I am a bit confused about how people calculate p-value when calculating odds-ratios.

The log-odds ratio (LOR) for a contingency table with two entries is $L = \log \frac{p_{1}}{p_{0}}$ and has an unbiased estimator using sampled frequencies: $\hat{L} = \log \frac{n_{1}}{n_{0}}$. This estimator has asymptotic variance $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_0}}$, which allows you to assign confidence intervals to the estimated LOR. If you also want to assign a p-value to the observed sample LOR, then you'd need the variance around the null hupothesis of a LOR of zero, which in this case, since $n_1+n_2=N$ and $n_1 = n_0$, is equal to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{N}}$. This is independent of the population parameters since it only depends on the total number of samples, which makes it a pivotal statistic. This means you can shift the distribution to zero to calculate probabilities under the null hypothesis of a LOR of zero, and assign p-values. No problems there.

**However** The LOR for a contingency table with four entries is $L = \log \frac{p_{11}p_{00}}{p_{10}p_{01}}$ and has an unbiased estimator using sampled frequencies: $\hat{L} = \log \frac{n_{11}n_{00}}{n_{10}n_{01}}$. This estimator has variance $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_{11}} + \frac{1}{n_{00}} + \frac{1}{n_{01}} + \frac{1}{n_{10}}}$.

While this still allows you to construct a confidence interval, it is (if I understand correctly) no longer a pivotal statistic: the variance depends on the observed frequencies and thus the population parameters.

Still, I see people calculate p-values associated to nonzero LORs (see for example this discussion: [How to calculate the p.value of an odds ratio in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156861/how-to-calculate-the-p-value-of-an-odds-ratio-in-r)). How is that possible? Am I missing something? Are there hidden assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a likelihood-based binomial regression, as suggested by [Frank Harrell](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/156913/28500) and [Ben Bolker](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/156863/28500) on the [page you cite](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156861/how-to-calculate-the-p-value-of-an-odds-ratio-in-r), or use [log-linear analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis) of counts in a contingency table, the *p*-values are based on the [asymptotic normality of the maximum-likelihood estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Efficiency). The test statistic is then a pivotal *z*-statistic from which confidence intervals can be calculated. There remains a question of whether there are enough cases to be close enough to asymptotic normality, but that's an issue for all maximum-likelihood estimation.

Agresti devotes Chapter 3 of the second edition of [Categorical Data Analysis](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0471249688) to "Inference for Contingency Tables." Sections 3.5 and 3.6 discuss relative advantages of different methods for small samples, where the highly discrete nature of the data poses particular problems.