# How can I calculate variance of log Odds Ratio if Odds Ratio extracted from the study is pre-calculated?

Tags: r, variance, meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I want to conduct a meta-analysis using odds ratio as my metric. The studies I am using provided pre-calculated odds ratios only, along with their confidence intervals and/or standard error. I need variance of log odds ratio in order to conduct the analysis; however, I am unsure how to extract it. Can anybody help please?

Thanks.

Comment: step 1: Log transform the CI, the log of the reported odd ratio should be the midpoint. step 2: Calculate the interval half-width. This length is the 1-alpha/2 z-score times the SE of the log odds ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Chapter 6 of the [Cochrane Handbook for Systematic Reviews of Interventions](https://training.cochrane.org/handbook/current/chapter-06) explains how to proceed in such cases. Sections 6.3.1 and 6.3.2 are especially relevant to your situation.

If the authors provide standard errors, I strongly suspect that they are for the log-odds ratio and not the odds ratio, as standard errors for the odds ratio are [problematic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156597/how-to-calculate-se-of-an-odds-ratio). Typically, a logistic regression model reports such standard errors on the log-odds scale (see example below).

If the authors provide a confidence interval for the odds ratio, you can approximate the standard error using the following formulae. Denote the point estimate of the odds ratio as $OR$ and $L$ and $U$ the lower and upper limits of a $(1-\alpha)\%$-confidence interval for the odds ratio (e.g. a $95\%$-confidence interval). Further, denote the $1-\alpha/2$-quantile of the standard normal distribution as $z_{1-\alpha/2}$. A $(1-\alpha)\%$ Wald confidence interval for the odds ratio is:

\begin{align*}
\log(OR) + z_{1-\alpha/2}\times \operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) &= \log(U)\\
\log(OR) - z_{1-\alpha/2}\times \operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) &= \log(L)
\end{align*}

Rearranging the formulae, we can get the (approximate) standard error for the log-odds ratio as follows:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) &= \frac{\log(U) - \log(OR)}{z_{1-\alpha/2}}\\
\operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) &= \frac{\log(OR) - \log(L)}{z_{1-\alpha/2}}\\
\operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) &= \frac{\log(U) - \log(L)}{2z_{1-\alpha/2}}
\end{align*}

The standard error can also be calculated from the $P$-value. Denote $\Phi^{-1}(p/2)$ the standard normal quantile corresponding to a two-sided $P$-value of $p$. The standard error can then be calculated using the following equation:

$$
\operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) = \left|\frac{\log(OR)}{\Phi^{-1}(p/2)}\right|
$$

Let's try it using an example in `R` using artificially generated data. Here, I generate only one continuous predictor `x` with a log-odds ratio of $5/21$:

```
# Sample size
n <- 20

# Generate data
set.seed(142857)
x <- runif(n, 18, 60)           
z <- -(65/7) + (5/21)*x  
pr <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))
y <- rbinom(n, 1, pr)

dat <- data.frame(y = y, x = x)

# Calculate logistic regression model
summary(mod <- glm(y~x, family = binomial))

            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -7.62463    3.13999  -2.428   0.0152 *
x            0.20233    0.09059   2.234   0.0255 *

# Wald 95%-confidence intervals
confint.default(mod, level = 0.95)

                   2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) -13.77890599 -1.4703548
x             0.02478875  0.3798772
```

The logistic regression reports the results on the log-odds scale. Accordingly, we have $\log(OR) = 0.20233, \log(L) = 0.0248, \log(U) = 0.3799, P = 0.0255$. As we have calculated $95\%$-confidence interval, we have $z_{1-\alpha/2} \approx 1.96$. Also, from the two-sided $P$-value of $0.0255$ we get $\Phi^{-1}(p/2)=\Phi^{-1}(0.0255/2) = -2.234$. Plugging those values into the formulae above, we get:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) &= \frac{0.3799 - 0.20233}{1.96} = 0.0906\\
\operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) &= \frac{0.20233 - 0.0248}{1.96} = 0.0906\\
\operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) &= \frac{0.3799 - 0.0248}{3.92} = 0.0906\\
\operatorname{SE}(\log(OR)) &= \left|\frac{0.20233}{-2.234}\right| = 0.0906
\end{align*}

All methods recover the standard error which is $0.09059$ in the output.